# Lollipop - Device's users management

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, user-management

In `Android Lollipop`, is it possible to retrieve the list of `User`s in a device? I'm speaking of those selected by pressing the user's profile pic in the quicksetting drawer.

What other **actions** can we take on these users?

- Retrieve *list* of users?
- Retrieve user's *profile pic*?
- *Change* from one user to another?
- At least use an *Intent* to open the default usesr management page?

Comment: Have you tried `AccountManager.getAccounts()`?

Comment: The `AccountManager` class provides access to a centralized registry of the user's online accounts. This question is about something different.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of information can be found in the [`UserManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html) object. This class manages users and user details on a multi-user system.

This class has a method `getUserProfiles` which returns a list of `UserHandles` for profiles associated with the user that the calling process is running on, including the user itself. A [`UserHandle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserHandle.html) is a representation of a user on the device.

Another useful class is [`DevicePolicyManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#createUser(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String)).
To switch between users you can use [`switchUser`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#switchUser(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.UserHandle)) in `DevicePolicyManager`

This is also described [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html), where the new Android 5.0 API's are explained.

To open the default user management page, you can use this `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.USER_SETTINGS");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I can't find official documentation for this action, but you can verify this in the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml). I have also tested this on Android 5.0.